# how to import xml to mysql using load xml

Tags: mysql, xml

I m very new on mysql.
I have a table like;

Create TABLE MSISDN_NumberRange(CC INT(3) NULL, NDC INT(10) NULL, SN_RangeStart INT(10) NULL, SN_RangeStop INT(10) NULL );

also xml as below.

```
<CCITT_E164_NumberSeries>
          <MSISDN_NumberRanges>
            <RangeData>
              <NumberRange>
                <CC>237</CC>
                <NDC>69</NDC>
              </NumberRange>
            </RangeData>
            <RangeData>
              <NumberRange>
                <CC>237</CC>
                <NDC>655</NDC>
              </NumberRange>
          </MSISDN_NumberRanges>
          <GT_NumberRanges>
            <RangeData>
              <NumberRange>
                <CC>237</CC>
                <NDC>69</NDC>
              </NumberRange>
            </RangeData>
          </GT_NumberRanges>
          <MSRN_NumberRanges>
            <NumberRange>
              <CC>237</CC>
              <NDC>69</NDC>
              <SN_Range>
                <SN_RangeStart>0001000</SN_RangeStart>
                <SN_RangeStop>0001999</SN_RangeStop>
              </SN_Range>
            </NumberRange>
            <NumberRange>
              <CC>237</CC>
              <NDC>69</NDC>
              <SN_Range>
                <SN_RangeStart>0002000</SN_RangeStart>
                <SN_RangeStop>0002999</SN_RangeStop>
              </SN_Range>
            </NumberRange>
           </MSRN_NumberRanges>
        </CCITT_E164_NumberSeries>
```

I want to get MSISDN series to one table and others to other table but first I m trying to get just MSISDN series.

When I specify ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '' I m getting only one random value.

When I specify ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '' I m getting all ranges for MSISDN MSRN and GT ranges.

Please asist me to solve this.